# how can i set some image view and show all of them

Tags: android, xml

I want to set some PNG images one over each other in an Android application.
And show one or some of them together by clicking on a button.
But when I tried to set some ImageView over another ImageView, the application crashed.

Here is my xml layout code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#ff0000">

<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/freepizza"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:src="@drawable/gobalak_kam"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView9" android:background="@drawable/goje_motevaset"/>
```

and it's error log codes:

```
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): Process: com.kayra.pitza, PID: 3484
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kayra.pitza/com.kayra.pitza.Kitchen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.kayra.pitza.Kitchen.onCreate(Kitchen.java:17)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     ... 11 more
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     ... 24 more
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     ... 27 more
```

I have to do this, but I don't have any idea about how to.

Please help me.
How can I set some image over each other in xml?

Comment: Can you clarify on "the applicatin broke down"

Comment: Explain the error more clearly. Post more code. Help us out so you can help...

Comment: @shkschneider I posted error log in question

Comment: Post the entire XML layout

Comment: @shkschneider i posted again :)

Comment: is this the entire xml layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
04-30 11:42:07.827: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
```

You got OOM exception there are a lot of ways to solve it one could be adding

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

to your application manifest tag. Also read:

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

to see the standard way.

Comment: Change the resolution of your images I mean change the pixels !

Comment: "i just try to set some imageview over another imageview" can you tell me why? what do you want to create?

Comment: I want to show some object as image, over each other. when buttun pressed, show another image over it to cover together

Comment: change your image size to 300 * 300 pixels !

Answer (score 0):

Create a resource folder named `drawable-nodpi` and place your images in that folder instead of `drawable`, it may help sort out your problem!

Comment: are you using high resolution images?

Comment: no. i just try to set some imageview over another imageview and i got this error

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative Layout instead of Linear layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
     />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageview2"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope It Will help You , Thanks